# data reorganization by every image

Tags: c

I have for example a matrix (inA) which is full of values from 0 to 23.

The data for image 0 are  : 0,2,4,6,...

The data for image 1 are : 1,3,5,7...

I want to reorganize the dat to another matrix (ouB) by every image.
So , ouB must be:   0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16...,1,3,5,7,9...

Right now ouB is : 0,2,4,6,1,3,5,7,8,10,12...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    int NbOfElmts = 4 , NbOfTech = 3 , NbOfImages = 2;

    int *inA =  malloc( NbOfElmts * NbOfTech * NbOfImages * sizeof( *inA ) );
    int *ouB =  malloc( NbOfElmts * NbOfTech * NbOfImages * sizeof( *ouB )  );


    //fill inA
    for ( int i = 0; i <  NbOfTech; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < NbOfElmts; j++ )
        {
            for ( int k = 0; k < NbOfImages; k++ )
            {
                inA[ i * NbOfElmts * NbOfImages + j * NbOfImages + k ] = i * NbOfElmts * NbOfImages + j * NbOfImages + k;
            }
            printf( "\n Data for #0 image: %d ",i * NbOfElmts * NbOfImages + j * NbOfImages );
            printf( "\n Data for #1 image: %d ",i * NbOfElmts * NbOfImages + j * NbOfImages + 1 );
        }

    }

    // print inA
    for ( int i = 0; i < NbOfTech; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < NbOfElmts; j++ )
        {
            for ( int k = 0; k < NbOfImages; k++ )
            {
                printf("\nA = %d",inA[ i * NbOfElmts * NbOfImages + j * NbOfImages + k ] );
            }
        }
    }


    printf("\n");
    // copy inA elements to ouB organized per Image
    for ( int i = 0; i <  NbOfTech; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < NbOfElmts; j++ )
        {
            for ( int k = 0; k < NbOfImages; k++ )
            {
                ouB[ i * NbOfElmts * NbOfImages + k * NbOfElmts + j ] = inA[ i * NbOfElmts * NbOfImages + j * NbOfImages + k ];
                //ouB[ i * NbOfElmts * NbOfImages + j * NbOfImages + k ] = inA[ i * NbOfElmts * NbOfImages + k * NbOfElmts + j ];
            }
        }
    }

    // print ouB
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < NbOfElmts * NbOfTech * NbOfImages; i++ ) 
        printf( "\nB = %d",ouB[ i ] );



    printf("\n");
    free ( inA );
    free ( ouB );

    return 0;
}
```

The whole problem is here:

```
ouB[ i * NbOfElmts * NbOfImages + k * NbOfElmts + j ] = inA[ i * NbOfElmts * NbOfImages + j * NbOfImages + k ];
```

Comment: Where is your question?

Comment: @Jens Gustedt:in the beginning.I say I want to organize ouB so , it  goes : 0,2,4,6,8,10..1,3,5,7  and not as it is now :  0,2,4,6,1,3,5,7,8,10,12...

Comment: I captured that. Still there is no question. Please cook your code example down to a minimal example that observes the behavior that you are after, and then ask a real question about that behavior.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: Sorry, but this is the most minimal example I can show!I think the question is clear.Organize data by every image.

Comment: That's a task, not a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
ouB[ k*NbOfElmts*NbOfTech + i * NbOfElmts  + j ] = inA[ i * NbOfElmts * NbOfImages + j * NbOfImages + k ];
```

instead of:

```
ouB[ i * NbOfElmts * NbOfImages + k * NbOfElmts + j ] = inA[ i * NbOfElmts * NbOfImages + j * NbOfImages + k
```

Comment: :Excellent!!Thanks a lot!If you could let me know how did you think of that? (the ouB indexing)

Comment: Well, you wanted a reordering where `k` index is running with the biggest step, then `i` and finally `j`. I.e. `k` will be multiplied by two other dimensions, `i` by the remaining one and finally `j` without multiplier.